# Identifying an old (horror?) movie/tv episode involving cyborgs

Tags: story-identification, cyborg

I was watching "Beyond Human" when a section came up regarding people's negative reactions to the idea of cybernetics. To make this point, the documentary discussed how cyborgs are often villains in science fiction and showed a clip featuring some sort of cybernetic creature. It was a short clip and confusingly shot so I can't really say for certain what's happening, but it looks like someone is being absorbed/taken over by a bunch of wires or metal tendrils or something. Some guy covered in wires starts fizzing or buzzing at the end. The footage is in black and white and has a bit of a fifties monster-movie aesthetic to it.

The clip is found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tW7Fy5rHLgk), about [32 seconds in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tW7Fy5rHLgk&t=32s).

I've never seen the movie/episode that this comes from but I'm very curious. Anyone know where this footage is from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's [Tetsuo: The Iron Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetsuo:_The_Iron_Man), a Japanese movie from 1989. You can see some of the same footage at 2:13 in the trailer here: